# totally disconnected sets and homeomorphisms

Tags: gn.general-topology

For every totally disconnected perfect subset S in the plane one finds
a homeomorphism of the plane onto itself mapping S onto the ternary Cantor set. 
This is an exercise in a book by Engelking and Sieklucki.
I am interested in a  proof of this result. 
Thanks.

Comment: The following MSE Question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726712/homeomorphism-of-cantor-set-extends-to-the-plane has an answer calling the above Schonflies teorem, suggesting a book by Moise. See a paper by Bing (only stating the result) http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103037324 For a proof I would think of a sequence of homeomorphisms each "disturbing" your set just a little so that at the end the Cantor set becomes the graph of a function (after which it ought to be easy), but didn't think of the details, there might be a better approach. Google plane homeomorphism Cantor set

Answer (score 4):

Theorem 7, page 93, of "Geometric Topology in Dimensions 2 and 3" by E.E.Moise. Incidentally, one should not call it "Schoenflies theorem", even though, it has a similar flavor.